# How can I select a range of cells in non-consecutive columns up to last empty row?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to create a chart from a DB, and I need to select the data in 3 non consecutive columns (A, D and K) up the last non-empty row.

```
Private Sub TRAFFIC_BT_Click()
'
' web_traffic Macro
' Create a chart to show the evolution of web_traffic stats
'

'
    Dim szTodayDate As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet


    Set WS = Sheets("DB")

    LastRow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds the last row with text


    szTodayDate = Format(Date, "mmm-dd-yyyy")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Web Traffic Report " + szTodayDate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("DB!A1:A72, DB!$D1:$D72, DB!$K1:$K72")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Web Traffic report " + szTodayDate


End Sub
```

With this code I am plotting in the chart from A1 to A72, D1 to D72... But I want to change "72" for LastRow

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the lastrow variable into the range instead of using 72.

```
Private Sub TRAFFIC_BT_Click()
'
' web_traffic Macro
' Create a chart to show the evolution of web_traffic stats
'

'
    Dim szTodayDate As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet



    Set WS = Sheets("DB")

    LastRow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds the last row with text


    szTodayDate = Format(Date, "mmm-dd-yyyy")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Web Traffic Report " + szTodayDate

    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("DB!A1:A" & lastrow & ", DB!$D1:$D" &  lastrow & ", DB!$K1:$K" & lastrow & ")

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Web Traffic report " + szTodayDate


End Sub
```